# Method with two parameters in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How can I make a method with two parameters using ASP.NET Web Api?

So that I can call it like localhost/controller/param1/param2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change or add route in global.asax

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi1", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{name}", Defaults: new{} );
```

Answer (score 57):

You can also call the url with specific params names in the querystring:

```
/api/actions?param1=5&param2=1/1/2000
```

Then the controller method would be:

```
GetByParams(int param1, DateTime param2)
```

Comment: This is the better answer. The accepted answer works, but the URL doesn't make as much sense. /id/name works out to something like this for a URL: http://www.mysite/api/DoStuff/12345/Vince. That doesn't make much sense. Like "Vince" is some item in the "12345" category. http://www.mysite/api/users/Vince makes a lot more sense or http://www.mysite/api/users?name=Vince&id=12345

Comment: Great Answer. Exactly what i was wanting.

Comment: Coul you provide a link to the official details about the GetByParams method? I have not been able to locate it. I have tested it, though, and it works as you described.

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest way is to simply use `AttributeRouting`.

```
[Route("api/YOURCONTROLLER/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]
public string Get(int paramOne, int paramTwo) {
    return "The [Route] with multiple params worked";
}
```

The `{}` names need to match your parameters.

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Man I used this 1000 times, and always thought It was sort of a "hack" and there is better way. Seems like this is actually best practice..